# Sorting a collection in Cypher and ordering results in the same order as the collection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Cypher and I'm trying the following. I have a graph where the relationships have a numeric property. I want to write a query like:

```
start n=node(*)
match n-[r *1..3]->m
return n,m, r
order by r.myproperty
```

This doesn't work since `r` in this case is a collection.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to do at the moment. I've been wanting to implement some functionality to handle it--my idea is here:

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/30

Please comment on the issue if you'd like to see it happen.